# can I edit matrix cells based on their value?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix in which every has either the value 1 or 0. What I want to know is, is there a way to change all "cells" with value one into a certain string?

Comment: Matrix as a 2d array ?

Comment: Is this numpy or a 2-dimensional list?

Comment: Please provide more information about your matrix. (type and sample)

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean value of `0` and `1` (False and True) to use operator `and`

```
0 and "a" > 0
1 and "a" > "a"
```

Giving

```
values = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
s = "a"
values = [[v and s for v in row] for row in values]
print(values)  # [[0, 'a', 0], ['a', 'a', 'a'], [0, 0, 0], ['a', 0, 'a']]
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is yes Kobus, we can call the values inside the matrix directly instead of its address.

***Procedure***:
   Instead of using the location, just use the value of the element while mentioning it. 
      For example, if you are using python, you can use

```
for i in values:
    if str(i) =="1":
        i=="random"
print(values)
```

Now, check the values, it was changed.